# scala json property value cleanup: single item array to item and property deletion for empty array

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have multiple json string lines. I loaded them as a DataFrame.
After merging data by Id, for an Id, all properties become arrays like:

```
{"id":123, "color":[A,B,C], "year":[1999], "nickname":[], "process":[[...]], ...}
```

I want to make this kind of json lines to:

```
{"id":123, "color":[A,B,C], "year":1999, "process":[...], ...} // deleting "nickname"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: How are you doing the merge?

Comment: I did it like:     val collectionDRs = (drs.columns.toSet - "id").map(c=>collect_set(c).as(c)).toSeq  
val result = drs.groupBy("id").agg(collectionDRs.head, collectionDRs.tail: _*)